# Poblem with VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

Installed the "Auto Close Tag" extension for VS Code, but for some reason it does not work. The description of the extension shows that it closes tags automatically. In my case, the tag is closed only after pressing the combination (Alt + .) Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an extension, you can enable linked editing in VSCode.

Add this to your settings.json file:

```
"editor.linkedEditing": true
```

This controls whether the editor has linked editing enabled. Depending on the language, related symbols, e.g. HTML tags, are updated while editing.

Also, you can add this to automatically close tags in html:

```
"html.autoClosingTags": true,
"javascript.autoClosingTags": true,
"typescript.autoClosingTags": true
```

See [here](https://www.roboleary.net/vscode/2020/08/05/dont-need-extensions.html) for some additional information if needed.

Comment: I did this but nothing has changed. Maybe I don't understand something. I made these changes to settings.json
https://imgur.com/BeSyzuz

Comment: Hmm. In my install the editor will auto-close tags for me in an html file whether I have that setting enabled or not. Try checking for updates in VSCode and try checking if you have HTML Language Features and some other built-in extensions in Extensions > ••• > Show Running Extensions?

Comment: @Dronikon Try adding this: {
  "html.autoClosingTags": true,
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": true,
  "typescript.autoClosingTags": true
}